# Override Nebular media breakpoints

Tags: css, angular, media, breakpoints, nebular

Is there a way to override media breakpoints in Nebular?
I'd need to customize the 'md' value from 768px to 800px, in order to uniform the portrait mode of Samsung tablets and IPad.

Comment: Surely those breakpoints will be based on variables, so - https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/design-system/enable-customizable-theme

Comment: I'm not sure about that because media breakpoints don't belong to the theme, they are cross themes